# A non statistical/mathematical analogy to max vs argmax

Tags: interpretation, simulation, terminology, extreme-value

I recently had a discussion on the topic 'usefulness/awareness of the function `argmax()` in non descriptive analysis'. That means areas, where you do not want to show maximum sales or maximum units, or in other word just a maximum of a value, but want to pass the information about the location.

It was asserted that many people in their programs mostly calculate the `max()` and then search for the index of that specific value, which is quite inefficient. Where as `argmax()` already has the id of the max, and the value (indirectly), which is more desirable as we sometimes want to pass the maximum in non descriptive areas, e.g. the id of clusters, where we had a max or something like that.

Just that we are on the same page, here is an example for max and argmax, giving the max value/id of a numpy array in python:

```py
    np.array([123, 2324, 43, 5436, 23, 4, 8, 434, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 45, 32]).max()
    gives: 5436
    np.array([123, 2324, 43, 5436, 23, 4, 8, 434, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 45, 32]).argmax()
    gives: 3
```

Here comes the question (and why its on CV):
I came up with an analogy, I'm not sure, if it really catches this statement above about max and argmax 100% correctly. Imagine I want to explain it to someone with no programming/stats background. Do you have a better one or is this analogy sufficient or too simplistic, what comes into your mind? I have the feeling that it does not cover the max aspect well enough, but only general indexing.

*Imagine you are in front of a locked door, which you want to open. Right beside you is a key rack with keys of different shapes. You take one key, and see if it fits. You see that the key doesn't fit and you take the next one, until you have the final key, which fits the door.
The difference between max and argmax is, that calculating a max is like taking the key, open the door, deposit the key, without remembering its position on the rack, only its shape. While with argmax you remember which position the key was, so you dont have to try all keys again, and next time and don't care about the shape, although you know it*

Comment: isn't argmax 4 in your example? I think the analogy is not helpful because it introduces alot of things that could confuse someone. The concept itself is simple enough that just using some examples should make it clear.

Comment: python counts from 0

Comment: In your analogy, a key either works or doesn't work. This is a search problem. It doesn't capture the typical optimization problem where there are many possible values, and we want to find the (location of) the greatest value. The analogy also confuses the values being compared (which is whether the key works, not its shape). You also haven't established any ordering on the values; why is a key working considered 'greater than' not working? I.e. why is the correct key the result of the $\arg \max$ operation rather than the $\arg \min$ operation?

Comment: Perhaps a clearer analogy: We're interested in the height of buildings in a city. The $\max$ operation gives the height of the tallest building, whereas the $\arg \max$ operation gives its address. This can also be extended to continuous optimization problems, where we seek the maximum of a function rather than a discrete array. Suppose we can measure the altitude at any point in a mountain range. The $\max$ operation gives the altitude of the tallest peak, whereas the $\arg \max$ operation gives its GPS coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot user20160. I appreciate your answer and your critique!

Comment: @user20160 I like your example because it centers the two essential concepts: the data, and the index into the data. I came here to write something very similar Perhaps you could write up your comment as an answer?

Comment: I fear that forcing an analogy between the *shape* of a key and the *magnitude* of a function potentially would confuse the issue for some readers.  That's why @user20160's example works better.

Comment: The reason why you need an analogy at all is because Python went with the very mathematical `argmax` instead of a simply descriptive alternative, like R's equivalent function `which.max` (i.e. *which* object has the maximum value, not what is that value).